# How to programatically hide checkbox column (aka TabularView) on XsltListViewWebPart?

Tags: list-view

By default, the list view web part comes with a column containing a checkbox for each list row.

With the UI, it's possible to disable it by going into view's options and disabling the **Allow individual item checkboxes** option in the **Tabular View** section.

Is it possible to apply this setting programatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This setting is reflected as TabularView in the view XML definition. However, setting it on the view via CSOM seems not to be supported.

I managed to achieve the desired result with Client Side Rendering. I've injected the below JavaScript code with JSLink:

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

    overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;
    overrideCtx.OnPreRender  = postRenderHandler;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();

function postRenderHandler(ctx) {
   ctx.ListSchema.TabularView = false;
}
```